# using a for each loop with pointers

Tags: visual-c++, pointers, vector, struct, foreach

First of I have 2 Classes in 2 files (both .h and .cpp files), *Create.h* and *AI.h*.

Create.h has this struct in it:

```
public:
    struct Cell
        {
            //some stuff
            vector<Cell*> neighbors;
            State state;
        };
```

Here is the enum class State (stored in the Create.h file):

```
enum class State : char
{
    //some states like "empty"
};
```

Now in AI.cpp I have a function like this:

```
void AI::Function(Create::Cell cell)
{
        for each (Create::Cell* var in cell.neighbors)
        {
            if (var->state == State::empty)
            {

            }
        }
}
```

So basically I am trying to access each individual Cell which is stored in cell.neighbors with a for each so I can do some stuff to each one of them.

According to my debugger though it doesn't even reach the *if (var->state == State::empty)* part. Am I using the for each wrong?

EDIT: The neighbors vector has definitely elements in it

[image: neighbors vector]

Comment: Are you using poor taste macros for `each` and `in`? Otherwise, your code is not even legal _C++_

Comment: @K-ballo check out at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Are you sure you've entered neighbors?

Comment: @ReedCopsey 100% sure, I checked it in the debugger

Comment: The c++ tag is wrong: it is c++/cli

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Thank you for confirming this is not C++

Comment: @K-ballo actually it is c++, but it is microsoft extension, so it is MS c++ :)

Comment: @IlyaBursov: That is not by definition C++. Besides, the link you gave us shows that `/clr` is required for it to work.

Comment: Please take this conversation to the chat box.

Comment: @K-ballo: `/clr` is not needed, it works in native code and on native containers.  Fixing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling with optimizations enabled, then an empty `if` statement like that might be completely removed (it has no side-effects).

(Although, I think the debugger won't let you set a breakpoint on that line, if it were removed.  So this is an easy test -- try to set a breakpoint on the `if` itself.)

Comment: Absolutely correct, I added an `int a = 3;` before the if statement and then an `a = 5` inside the if statement to check if it will get inside and it did. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the vector is empty. You can check this printing its size before the loop.
And I would like to answer some comments. This form of the for loop is MS VC++ language extension. It is not C++/CLI.

Comment: vector is definitely not empty, I checked it in the debugger

Comment: Does the compiler issue some warnings?

Comment: Also what does this mean  (two different qualifier) Create::Cell and Maze::Cell?

Comment: No compiler warnings. Also edited the qualifier (was a mistake from copy paste)